# Does the value of unit tests decrease with the complexity of the unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, architecture, theory, software-design

I'm at the point where I should write a unit test for the complex algorithm that my function does perform. The function takes two mandatory arguments at invocation. Based on the combination of both arguments the function does return something.

```
function ReturnDesiredParagraphStyle(currParagraphStyle, nextParagraphStyle) 
{
    // logic
}
```

Now the problem is, to test any combination of inputs and the correctness of the desired output of the function I have to write a complex logic within the unit test, because there are so many possible inputs (approximately 50 for each argument). The complex logic would be a loop with the purpose that I do not have to type each combination of inputs manually in the unit test.

I do understand that most of the time to write this unit-test will provide an layer of safety, but doesen't it lead the concept of unit testing a bit ad absurdum (because the logic in the unit test will be so complex and nothing tests the logic in the unit test)?

Comment: Writing complex logic in order to be lazy and not properly write your tests is wrong. You only have to write the tests once, so take the time to do it properly and be done with it.

Comment: Why do you not write this as an answer? Problem is there are so many, maybe too many combinations of inputs to the function to just write them all manually in the unit test.

Comment: If my math is correct there are around 2450 combinations of inputs. That is to much to type it manually in the unit test.

Comment: If you're not going to properly test the code, then don't bother writing the tests at all. They're worthless, because you can a) miss a combination of inputs, b) introduce an error into your *complex logic* that incorrectly tests, and c) introduce a new error at any point in that *complex logic* that breaks all the tests. If you're not going to do it properly, why do it at all? Just run your code while you pray that it works.

Comment: But do you not think 2450 combinations are too much? What if there are 10000 combinations (which is easily possible with just a few more inputs). I think it's  a point where somebody who writes unit tests should think about. I think that at some point unit tests decrease in value or are just impossible to write if there's no complex logic in the unit test that saves you from typing all combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your complex logic in the unit test will exactly be the logic that you wrote in the function that you want to test. So that would make no sense at all.

At some point, when a function does compute a return value based on two or more arguments, it just becomes almost impossible to write a unit test if the count of different input-combinations is too high. And that does happen pretty quickly (exponential).

But of course testing just a few different combinations does make some sense.